# What causes this (b+w and blurred) effect?

Tags: html, css

I wonder if somebody could give me any ideas as to what produces the blur/b+w effect on this site 
http://www.ralphlauren.com/home/index.jsp?ab=global_logo

when the mouse is over the menu bar the main slider is b+w and focus.  is this done using css animation?

thanks for input

Comment: If you see something cool on a website and want to see how they did it, push f12(on pc) to bring up the developer tools.  You can see all html and css for the site.  You can even change the css or html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was interested when I saw the link and dug it out. Nothing fancy.

```
@-webkit-keyframes blurred { 
  100% { -webkit-filter: blur(2px) grayscale(0.8); }  
}
@-webkit-keyframes unblurred { 
  100% { -webkit-filter: blur(0px) grayscale(0); }  
}
.navOver.no-touch #hero_carousel .slide,
.navOver.no-touch #hero_carousel .slide .slide_copy  {
  -webkit-animation:blurred 1s ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.no-touch #hero_carousel .slide,
.no-touch #hero_carousel .slide .slide_copy  {
  -webkit-animation:unblurred 1s ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

I knew these existed but didn't actually know you could use them. Be warned they are VERY resource intensive so you will need to use them sparingly.

Comment: thanks @Shan.  Much appreciated.  Same here. Not really used filters. Browser support if anyone else finds this http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters